# Simple Harmonic Motion question from an old Applied Mathematics exam from the 70s... Am I right?

Tags: solution-verification, physics, classical-mechanics

I've been doing a few old Applied Mathematics exams from the 70s and would like some verification that my solution is correct.  Here is the problem:

*A particle of mass $m$ is attached to two elastic strings, each of natural length $a$. The other ends of the strings are fixed at points $A$ and $B$ on a horizontal table, where $AB = 2b (>2a)$, and the particle slides smoothly along the table along $AB$ in such a way that neither string slackens.*

*If an extension $a$ in either string produces a tension $kmg$ in that string, obtain an equation of motion for the particle, and hence write down the period of oscillation.*

*[8 marks]*

So here is the diagram I created.  $x$ denotes the displacement of the mass (at point $P$) in a general position during the motion.

[image]

The red dashed line indicated the extension. Using Hooke's Law, where $k_{s}$ is the stiffness of the spring.  (I am assuming $k_{s}$ is different to the $k$ given in the problem).

$$ T = k_{s}x $$
$$ k_{s} = \dfrac{T}{x} $$

Given $T = kmg$ when $x = a$.

$$ k_{s} = \dfrac{kmg}{a} $$

From the diagram:

Extension of string $AC$ is $(b - a) + x$.

Extension of string $BD$ is $(b - a) - x$.

Equation of motion for mass $m$ using Newton's Second Law is:
$$ T_2 - T_1 = m \ddot x $$
$$ k_{s} x_2 - k_{s} x_1 = m \ddot x $$

Where $x_2$ is the extension produces by $T_2$ and $x_1$ is the extension produces by $T_1$.

$$ \dfrac{kmg}{a} \big[ (b - a) - x \big] - \dfrac{kmg}{a} \big[ (b - a) + x \big] = m \ddot x $$

$$ \dfrac{kmg}{a} \big[ b - a - x - b + a - x \big] = m \ddot x $$

$$ \dfrac{kg}{a} \big[ -2x \big] = \ddot x $$

$$ \ddot x = - \dfrac{2kg}{a} x $$

This is in the form of SHM, $  \ddot x = - n^2 x $, where $n^2 = \dfrac{2kg}{a}$.

Period is given by $Period = \dfrac{2\pi}{n}$.

$$ Period = \dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{ \dfrac{2kg}{a}}} $$

$$  Period = \dfrac{2 \pi \sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2kg}} $$

$$ Period = \pi \sqrt{ \dfrac{2a}{kg} } $$

Well, that's my logic, can someone confirm the method is correct.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Note that springs are in parallel so you can use formula $k_{eff}=k_1+k_2$ to convert it to a single spring problem.

Comment: I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Usually you use $F$ for force (what you called $T$ because it was tension, I understand) and $T$ for the period. As for insipidintegrator's comment I completely disagree, there would be no oscillation with a single spring problem, the item would go one way and then not return, so obviously you cannot do that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct to me.

You could use only a single variable for $\omega=n$ though.

A nice feature is: $b$ does not show up in the end. This is expected, because of the linearity of Hooke's law.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - yeah I thought my solution looked OK, I was just trying to confirm my logic.